# Adding object to an existing ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arrayList with objects in one class and in other class I am getting that arrayList with all objects and want to add another new object to that ArrayList at end.

My code is at present is like this:

```
ArrayList<Student> studentName = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student student = new Student();
student.name("Jhon");
studentName.add(student);
//In another class I am getting the arrayList with existing objects

for (Student stu : ArrayList<Student> student){

System.out.printLn(stu.name);//prints existing student Name

// Here I want to add a new student name in the name arraylist at the end.

// output should be suppose.."Jhon", "Becky".
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You already add it. Which is the real question? Which is the issue you are facing?

Comment: From the comments, it looks like you want to modify a collection while iterating over it...BAD!!!!!!

Comment: Why don't you add all the students **then** print them? `List#add()` adds at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

try using ArrayList.addAll(...)